# schunk_svh_driver : Can't locate node svh_controller in package schunk_svh_driver

Tags: ros, roslaunch, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I download the packages schunk_svh_driver(
Source: git https://github.com/fzi-forschungszentrum-informatik/schunk_svh_driver.git)
in /opt/ros/indigo/share
and so, I Install the package by calling: apt-get install ros-indigo-schunk-svh-driver, but if I launch the controller node by calling : roslaunch schunk_svh_driver svh_controller.launch standalone:=true I get an error:

ERROR: cannot launch node of type [schunk_svh_driver/svh_controller]: can't locate node [svh_controller] in package [schunk_svh_driver].

Can you help me please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207610/schunk_svh_driver-:-can%27t-locate-node-svh_controller-in-package-schunk_svh_driver/) by [Alba](https://answers.ros.org/users/22228/alba/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2015-04-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-04-22**:
Can you clarify how you installed the package? Did you use `apt-get`, or did you clone it using git?

**Comment by [Alba](https://answers.ros.org/users/22228/alba/) on 2015-04-22**:
Hi, I clone it calling: sudo git clone https://github.com/fzi-forschungszentrum-informatik/schunk_svh_driver.git.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-04-22**:
And where do you clone it? In `/opt/ros/indigo/share`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I clone it calling: `sudo git clone https://github.com/fzi-forschungszentrum-informatik/schunk_svh_driver.git`

Packages you clone from github (or any package that you download the sources of) will need to be build in a catkin workspace before you can use them. If you really must install it from source, see the [catkin](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials) tutorials for how to do this. Don't do this in `/opt/ros/indigo/share` (in fact, **never** do this), but in a workspace you create in your home directory (for instance).

I'd really recommend you install it using `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-schunk-svh-driver` as shown on the [schunk_svh_driver](http://wiki.ros.org/schunk_svh_driver) wiki page, as that will already install the binaries and remove the need to build everything yourself.

The wiki page also shows you how to correctly setup everything the first time you use the package.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alba](https://answers.ros.org/users/22228/alba/) on 2015-04-23**:
Thank you for the answer. Are the drivers installed using sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-schunk-svh-driver the same that I can clone using git? Because using sudo apt-get I can move only 2 fingers of chunk hand (ring and little) when I launch roslaunch schunk_svh_driver svh_controller.launch.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-04-23**:
They should be, or at least very close.

If you have troubles using the driver, please open a new question here, on ROS Answers, or open an issue on the [issue tracker](https://github.com/fzi-forschungszentrum-informatik/schunk_svh_driver/issues) of the package.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-04-23**:
Also: don't forget to remove the cloned `schunk_svh_driver` directory from `/opt/ros/indigo/share` if it is still there (the debian pkg also installs files there, so make sure you don't remove those).

**Comment by [Alba](https://answers.ros.org/users/22228/alba/) on 2015-04-24**:
thanks a lot!

**Comment by [heppner](https://answers.ros.org/users/20042/heppner/) on 2015-06-06**:
The released version is the same as the Github Version. There might be very minor fixes in the Github version but they should not be notable to the average user. It can have several reasons that some fingers are not moving, look at the troubleshooting section at the wiki page for further details